# What's the use of 'sizeof...' operator in c++11? (not sizeof operator)

Tags: c++, operators

While reading `Discovering modern C++` by Peter Gottschling I found out that there is a new operator in c++11 named `sizeof...` . What's the usage of it? I could find only one reference about it over internet in [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof...).

Edit: This is `sizeof...` operator not `sizeof`.

Added this as a question here, as it was very difficult to get info about this operator during search. And hoping users will get the answer easier with this.

Comment: If you're using a variadic template (variable number of template arguments) it can be used to find the number of items in a [parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack). https://godbolt.org/z/6_NHY5

Comment: Please be more specific. Cppreference explains what it is and gives a simple example. What is not clear about it?

Comment: Ohh, I just added the question for future reference. I will modify the question for avoiding confusion.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, there are many tutorils online that explain the usage of this operator like [HERE](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_sizeof_operator.htm)

Comment: @anastaciu: It's sizeof... not sizeof :)

Comment: I tried to find duplicate questions (I can't really believe that this is asked for the first time.), but all the search engines ignore the ellipsis when searching for `sizeof...`, so this question will probably not be found either :(

Comment: @InQusitive, my bad, sorry...

Comment: @walnut: Yes, none of my search result actually showed anything related to it. But when I added cppreference this came up. Before that I thought it's a printing mistake in the book.