# Ellipsis ignored in search engines

Tags: search, search-engine

I noticed that ellipsis '...' is ignored in all search engines I tested, including in stackoverflow search engine, when trying to search literature to address this [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59693407/whats-the-use-of-sizeof-operator-in-c11-not-sizeof-operator/59693595#59693595), is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly not directly possible, most search engines ignore all punctuation. Google has made an effort to allow for certain types to be searched like "," or ".", but all of these are special cases and don't follow a general rule.
What you can do however is to search for "sizeof ellipsis" which brings the results of thoughtful writers.

Sidenote: "..." in particular is kind of special in common texts, there are lots of different ways to use it in printing, with differences in spacing, bracing, vertical position etc.. Also there is the possibility of using the single character HTML `&hellip;` which results in … as does Unicode U+2026.